# Clicking a link using URL based query

Tags: javascript

Off the bat, I am a complete novice to coding.

So, let's say for example, we've got `example.com`
And on `example.com`, there's a button that has `javascript:void(0)`. Is there a way to automatically click the button with something like `example.com/button:javascript:void(0)`.

If so, what do I type?
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If your question is about automating web browser behavior (e.g. button clicks), try looking for prior questions about web browser automation. It may also help to edit your question title to include the automation goal.

Comment: Short answer, no. Do your homework and read a bit more on javascript/dom and event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear from your example what you are trying to do but you can trigger clicks on buttons using `onclick()` and `.click()` ie;

```
<button id="myButton">Click me</button>

<script>
el = document.getElementById('myButton');
if (el.onclick) {
   el.onclick();
} else if (el.click) {
   el.click();
}
</script>
```

You can't trigger a click on an element via the URL alone however.